# variable file content using environment variables in linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have a script that reads from a configuration file with key-value pairs e.g.:

```
file /tmp/foo
weight 0.5
```

I would like to test several configurations e.g. several values for the weight key. I could of course make a configuration file for each weight, use that and remove it afterwards, but I was wondering whether I could instead make some sort of template file with variables inside like this:

```
file /tmp/foo
weight $WEIGHT
```

I would then call my script while setting the value for the WEIGHT variable:

```
env WEIGHT=0.5 ./my_script my_conf
```

Is this possible? It doesn't seem to work the way I described, but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Is your script a shell (ie. sh or bash) script?

Comment: No, it's a python script. Does it need to be a shell script for it to work?

Comment: No. It's just that as a shell script, if the format was `foo=bar`, you could source the file directly, and simply omit `weight`.